# How do I sort my NSSet Array for date added in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, assets

This is my Group+CoreDataProperty. I am currently sorting alphabetically with postName. Now I want to sort by date added. how do I change this?

```
extension Group {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Group> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Group>(entityName: "Group")
    }

    @NSManaged public var groupThumbnail: Data?
    @NSManaged public var groupTitle: String?
    @NSManaged public var home: Home?
    @NSManaged public var posts: NSSet?

    public var postsArr: [Post] {
        let set = posts as? Set<Post> ?? []
        return set.sorted {
            $0.postName ?? "" < $1.postName ?? ""
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to replace $0.postName ?? "" < $1.postName ?? "" with:

$0.postDate ?? "" < $1.postDate ?? "". But what do I replace "" with?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `postDate` is of type `Date` you can do

```
        $0.postDate ?? Date() < $1.postDate ?? Date()
```

The value after ?? defines what is used when the primary value is `nil`, so it always has to match the type of the original attribute. When `String` it has to be a string, e.g. `""`, when Date it has to be a Date. `Date()` would return the current date if the value is `nil` – which shouldn't be the case anyway.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the answer. I don't get the error message anymore. However, the list seems to update randomly. I don't think it is strictly sorted after date added.

Comment: I just realized I had a typo .. of course the second argument should say .postDate too.

Comment: Somehow I still get a warning message: "Value of type 'Date' has no member 'postDate'"

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI you would use the `@FetchRequest` property wrapper to fetch the `Post` entity with a predicate matching the `group` (that is the inverse of the `Group`'s `posts` relation) and a sort descriptor for the `dateAdded`.